A string that was already translated a long time ago doesn't show on the site
I edited the question (in the ruSO site), marked that this edit resolves the original close reason, the reopening failed and I got untranslated notification about it:

But it turned out that this string already translated long time ago (in October 2021). Is it a bug?
